# Como resolver este erro? Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter

Olá, pessoal!

Estou tentando um 'flutter build apk' no android 4.2.1, SDK java 21 e versão flutter 3.13.9, porém o build gera um erro conforme comentado na pergunta. Já tentei várias solucões, mas continua o mesmo erro. Não há também aquela janela de logs para verificar com detalhes da onde está vindo o erro.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           24,9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1